# Google chrome extension kwift.CHROME.min.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, console

Can someone know what is chrome-extension that is called by file `kwift.CHROME.min.js` ?

It is using this kind of link:

```
chrome-extension://random_string_here/content/contentScripts/kwift.CHROME.min.js
```

in my Chrome console I can see hundreds/thousands logs started with description `isElementCoveringWebui`

console log example:

```
isElementCoveringWebui
div.pcaflag
```

and code responsible for displaying above log:

```
  t.isWebUIFrameVisible = function (e, t) {
  const a = t.iframe;
  return a && (e => {
    const t = "EDGE" === n.getBrowser() ? ["BODY"] : ["BODY", "HTML"];
    return e.parentElement && t.some(t => t === e.parentElement.tagName)
  }
  )(a) && function () {
    let t;
    try {
      t = e.getCurrentWindow().getComputedStyle(a)
    } catch (e) {
      return !0
    }
    return o(t)
  }() && e.isReallyVisible({
    node: a,
    checkWholeArea: !0
  }) && !function (e, t) {
    const a = e.getCurrentDocument();
    let n = !1;
    const o = a.createTreeWalker(t.parentNode, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT);
    o.currentNode = t;
    const r = a => {
      console.log("isElementCoveringWebui"),
      console.log(a);
      const n = e.getCurrentWindow().getComputedStyle(a);
      return (() => "none" === n.pointerEvents)() && (() => "2147483647" === n.zIndex)() && (() => {
        const e = a.getBoundingClientRect()
          , n = t.getBoundingClientRect();
        return i.elementsHaveCommonArea(e, n)
      }
      )()
    }
      ;
    for (; o.nextNode() && !n;)
      n = r(o.currentNode);
    return n
  }(e, a)
}
```

Comment: Quick googling shows it's Dashlane extension. The posted code doesn't do anything particularly meaningful, it just detects/ensures visibility of elements added by the extension. You can uninstall the extension or set the console filter to exclude these messages e.g.  `-kwift.CHROME.min.js`

Comment: thanks @wOxxOm.. you are right.. it was annoying to see all logs..

Comment: the same script was taking 30% of the performance off of a game i was playing... so... also annoying for normal people (took me like 3 hours to find the actual culprit but hey atleast i now know how to use browser debugging tools lol)

Comment: I though i'd be hacked 

Answer (score 8):

The answer is simple: `kwift` scripts are part of the Dashlane.com browser extension.

Answer (score 0):

Moreover, its not quite random_string

> chrome-extension://random_string_here/content/contentScripts/kwift.CHROME.min.js

Its the extension id, and by googling "*chrome extension %random_string%*", you get the link to the extension you seek:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dashlane-%E2%80%94-password-manag/fdjamakpfbbddfjaooikfcpapjohcfmg